# Using an ArcGIS Online Web Experience in Offline Mode

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-experience-builder

I want to use an ArcGIS Online Web Experience in an environment where there is no internet connection. I installed the ArcGIS Experience Builder Developer Edition, created a new application, ran the server through node.js, specified the URL to my ArcGIS Online and added the Client ID given in the application. After those steps, I imported the Web Experience page from my account and downloaded it to my local disc. The content of the downloaded file is below:

[image: folder content]

When I start the server, I can reach this Web Experience through https://localhost:3001/. However, when I cut the internet connection, data inside the page disappears.

Is there a way to use a Web Experience fully offline?

Like embedding gdb data or shapefiles directly into the config.js file rather than using hosted feature services.

Comment: I don't think that Experience Builder is the right tool for offline apps.  You may want to consider a different architecture altogether.  If you require something that integrates with the ESRI environment, then you could start by researching at:  https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/mapping-apis-and-services/offline/ .  Although there are other non-ESRI options avaialble.  (Myself I built an iOS app that utilises GDAL and OpenLayers to work both online and offline.)